# How to edit page code with python mechanize?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, mechanize, mechanize-python

I have some code on page like this:

```
<div class="tabs1_cnt" id="pupil_tabs_content_2189609">
    <div class="pupil_tabs_content_item tabs1_cb" id="pupil_tabs_daybook_1111111" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="pupil_tabs_content_item tabs1_cb" id="pupil_tabs_timetable_1111111" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="pupil_tabs_content_item tabs1_cb" id="pupil_tabs_progress_1111111" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="pupil_tabs_content_item tabs1_cb" id="pupil_tabs_progress_clubs_1111111" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to edit this line *(2nd line)* with **python mechanize**:

```
<div class="pupil_tabs_content_item tabs1_cb" id="pupil_tabs_daybook_1111111" style="display: none;"></div>
```

to **remove** "style" **tag** *(like this)*:

```
<div class="pupil_tabs_content_item tabs1_cb" id="pupil_tabs_daybook_1111111">
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use find and after this slice your string:
For example:

````py
s = '<div class="pupil_tabs_content_item tabs1_cb" id="pupil_tabs_daybook_1111111" style="display: none;"></div>'
f = s.find('style')
final = s.find('"', f+8)
FINAL_STRING = s[:f] + s[final+1:]
print(FINAL_STRING)
# OUTPUT: <div class="pupil_tabs_content_item tabs1_cb" id="pupil_tabs_daybook_1111111" ></div>```
````